# I have many byte arrays; each is a string. How do I find the encoding each uses?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

I have an application that reads binary data from a database. Each byte array retrieved represents a string. The strings, though, have all come from different encodings (most commonly ASCII, UTF-8 BOM, and UTF-16 LE, but there are others). In my own application, I'm trying to convert the byte array back to a string, but the encoding that was used to go from string to bytes is not stored with the bytes. Is it possible in C# to determine or infer the encoding used from the byte array?

The use case is simplified below. Assume the byte array is always a string. Also assume the string can use any encoding.

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64(stringAsBytesAsBase64);
string originalString = Encoding.???.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: You can make intelligent guesses, but no.

Comment: Many byte arrays can represent valid string in multiple encodings, so there is no way to do that in general.

Comment: Is there another column that gives the encoding? Maybe as a fuller MIME type + charset ("Content-type")?

Comment: @TomBlodget No, if only... :( The strings are all XML documents that were read from a file system, but the files were read as strings and the method was not recorded. Now, some of the byte arrays clearly have UTF-8 or UTF-16 preamble and/or BOM, but encoding, MIME type, etc. are not recorded in the table (unless the XML content includes a declaration, but most sadly don't).

Comment: If you don't have any 'normal' extended-ascii encodings involved (like windows-1252) this should be fairly doable, actually. Strict ASCII compliance is really easy to check (all bytes lower than 128), and all UTF encodings follow strict byte patterns that can be detected.

Answer (score 0):

For text that is XML, the XML specification gives requirements and how to determine the encoding.

> In the absence of external character encoding information (such as
>   MIME headers), parsed entities which are stored in an encoding other
>   than UTF-8 or UTF-16 must begin with a text declaration (see 4.3.1 The
>   Text Declaration) containing an encoding declaration:
>
> …
>
> In the absence of information provided by an external transport
>   protocol (e.g. HTTP or MIME), it is a fatal error for an entity
>   including an encoding declaration to be presented to the XML processor
>   in an encoding other than that named in the declaration, or for an
>   entity which begins with neither a Byte Order Mark nor an encoding
>   declaration to use an encoding other than UTF-8.
>   —https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding

It seems that the storage design was to drop any "information provided by an external transport protocol". It is possible that what was stored meets the specification. You can inspect your data.

If the data is complete, just let your XML processing do the job:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64(stringAsBytesAsBase64);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
}
```

If you do need the XML back as text with a known encoding, you can then serialize it using whichever encoding you need.

Answer (score -1):

Someone downvoted this. Perhaps because it didn't start out with a clear answer:

> Is it possible in C# to determine or infer the encoding used from the byte array?

**No.**

Below is the best you can do and you'll see why it's problematic:

You can start with a list of known `Encodings.GetEncodings()` and eliminate possibilities. In the end, you will have **many known possibilities**, many known impossibilities and potentially unknown possibilities (for encodings that aren't supported in .NET, if any).  That is all as far a hard facts go.

You could then apply heuristics or some knowledge of expected content to narrow the list further. And *if* the results of applying each of the remaining encodings are all the same, then you've very probably got the correct text even if you didn't identify the original encoding.

Comment: You _can_ accurately detect byte order marks though; and it is perfectly possible to determine if a byte array is in a valid format for one of the various  UTF8 / UTF16 / UTF32 encodings. But if it _doesn't_ match, and you need to figure out messy 8-bit-per-character encodings... then it does get tricky.

Comment: The bytes for a BOM are valid characters in many encodings. But bytes matching a BOM does strongly shift the probability for a better guess of the corresponding Unicode encoding. But again, this is recovering lost metadata.

Comment: Even without BOMs though, given the strict binary patterns used in the UTF encodings, it is very much possible to _exclude_ encodings. And, to be fair, checking if something is pure-ascii-compliant  is completely trivial.

Comment: These comments help me. All these byte arrays are likely to represent UTF-8, UTF-16 LE, or UTF-16 BE string content. I can guess by looking at the first few bytes to check for BOMs, or, if BOM is missing, guess UTF-8. Thanks for the ideas all! There is an unlikely possibility that a string might be encoded with ASCII, which could lead to issues when guessing UTF-8 where BOM is not present. Is there a good way to differentiate without analyzing the entire byte array to check for out of out of bounds byte values for ASCII?